# Google: Cannot create API credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, credentials

In Google console API manager, if I click on "Credentials", a popup comes up up stating "Failed to load service accounts."

If I dismiss that and then try to "add credentials" and select "Oauth 2.0 Client ID" I get another popup that says "A required resource is not available."

When I dismiss that, the underlying page has an exclamation icon and says "Failed to load".

This happening to anyone else?  Just started failing this morning.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may have been a temporary block. I was having the same issues earlier today, but this afternoon I was able to get past the warning messages. I didn't do anything special outside of refreshing the page (which I did try earlier) and the errors didn't come up, leading me to believe there was some service disruption, but status.cloud.google.com only reported a Google Compute Engine issue.

Comment: You are correct that these errors are now gone, but I still am unable to use any of my Oauth 2.0 client credentials.
401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.

Comment: I've created new ones, tried renaming them, changed various settings, enabled and disabled the google+ api.  Nothing works.  I would love it if anyone could tell me if they are able to create new Oauth2 credentials.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? In my case I was setting up GAM on a new domain and successfully auth'd, so the process seems to be working now for me.

Comment: I still can't use Oauth.  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=[REMOVED]&client_id=[REMOVED]&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto

Results in a 401 page.

401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.

->Request Details
That’s all we know.